# Finding natural points on binary logarithm's graph?

Tags: number-theory, analysis, logarithms

Consider a binary logarithm function as $y =\log_2(ax + b)$ which is actually defined in $\mathbb{R}$. Now how can I find all the ponits on this function's graph whose both coordinates (x,y) belong to the set of natural numbers? Please note that $a,b \in\mathbb{N}$.

[The graph of $y = \log_2 (x)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCxHj.jpg)

I know that this graph is not for $\log_2 (ax + b)$, but when $x\in \mathbb{N}$ then $(ax + b) \in \mathbb{N}$ as well. As you see the black points (1,0) , (2,1) , (4,2) , (8,3) have both coordinates as Natural Value, but for example the point (6 , 2.59) is not natural. I mean how to calculate all points whose x & y are both Natural?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and include your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Let's move things around a bit.

$\log_{2}(ax+b)=y\ \ \implies\ \ ax+b=2^y$

Since we know that $y$ must be in the Natural Numbers, we can put it as:

$(ax+b)\in \{2,4,8,16,64...\}\ \ \implies\ \ x\in\{\frac{2-b}{a},\frac{4-b}{a},\frac{8-b}{a},\frac{16-b}{a},\frac{64-b}{a}...\}\cap \mathbb{N}$

After that, you just plug in all values of $x$ into your original equation to get your $y$. It's hard not to get any more specific without knowing $a$ and $b$, but we do know that $a$ must divide $(2^y-b)$

$a|(2^y-b)$

Comment: Please refrain from answering ill-posed questions. For more details see [EoQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards/33536#33536)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. $a \mid (2^y - b) \Rightarrow na = 2^y -b \Rightarrow y = \log_2 (na + b) \Rightarrow$ we get to the point we started. Now how to find the values of n so that the values of y will be natural?